# XLST not ignoring namespace prefix

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I have the following xmldata input, which should be transformed via xslt.
I simply want to extract the ns:something content. The dynamicNS namespace can be different during runtime.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dynamicNS:header>
  <ns:something>
    <ns:myid>1</ns:myid>
    <ns:myvalue>2</ns:myvalue>
  </ns:something>
</dynamicNS:header>
```

**The output should be:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <ns:something>
    <ns:myid>1</ns:myid>
    <ns:myvalue>2</ns:myvalue>
  </ns:something>
```

**I tried it with:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <ns:something>
          <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
      </ns:something>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this gives me the error: The prefix "dynamicNS" for element "dynamicNS:header" is not bound.;

I don't wan't to add the namespace for the dynamicNS because it can be different for each run.

What is the correct way to get my desired output?

Thanks guys.

Comment: The error message comes from the XML parser and tells you that in the input there is no namespace declaration for the prefix `dynamicNS`. That way the input is not namespace well-formed XML and as such not usable as input to XSLT/XPath as that requires namespace well-formed XML.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Your explanation makes sence. So now I add the namespace declaration manual to my xmldata which was generated from a data object. 

It works now but still I am not sure if my xslt implementation is the right choice. At least the result is fine now. 

Is it the best way for my transformation to use the xslt mentioned in the first post?

Comment: I don't see how the stylesheet code as posted could work as given the literal result element `ns:something` without any namespace declaration the XSLT isn't namespace well-formed either so I can't see how an XSLT processor would process it at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to omit the root element and its namespace declaration(s) and only copy its child elements then in XSLT 2 and later you can use

to make a copy of all child elements of the root, for instance the input

```
<dynamicNS:header xmlns:dynamicNS="http://example.com/foo">
  <ns:something xmlns:ns="http://example.com/ns">
    <ns:myid>1</ns:myid>
    <ns:myvalue>2</ns:myvalue>
  </ns:something>
</dynamicNS:header>
```

is transformed into the result

```
<ns:something xmlns:ns="http://example.com/ns">
    <ns:myid>1</ns:myid>
    <ns:myvalue>2</ns:myvalue>
  </ns:something>
```

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/gWcDMee

As I said already in the comments, both the input to XSLT as well as the stylesheet code need to be namespace well-formed XML documents, so the input and output you posted in the question with prefixes for which no namespace declarations exist do not allow XSLT processing.